# Straight-line distance as a function of camera angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

At a swim meet, a parent is videotaping his son from a seat in the stands that is $20$ meters past the starting line and $8$ meters away from his son's lane. Let $x$ represent the distance the son has swum.

1. Write $x$ as a function of $\theta$.
2. At what angle does the parent have the camera when the race is just starting?
3. At what angle does the parent have the camera when the son has swum $25$ meters.

Student note: There is a diagram with the question. I do not know if that matters too much, I do not think it will. I am very confused as to how I am supposed to set up an equation. And for item 1, I just want to say that $x$ is only part of the less than $20$ meters

Comment: The picture would be useful. Is the $8$ meters away via hypotenuse or measured purely horizontally.  My interpretation is $20^2 + x^2 = 8^2$ but it could be $20^2 + 8^2 = r^2$ as well.

Comment: Diagrams are often helpful as they will give you an idea as to how to proceed.  There should be some trigonometric formulas which describe ratios of sides of triangles that you learned.  Try to describe the scenario using triangles where one edge of the triangle is the distance to the part of the lane closest to the parent, and another edge of the triangle is the shortest distance of the parent to the lane the son swims in.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a diagram of the situation.

[image: diagram]

Notice that having swum $x$ meters, the top edge of the triangle becomes $20-x$ meters since the distance yet to travel plus the distance he has traveled should add up to $20$.

As for the angle of the bottom corner, you can describe it using $\theta = \arctan(\frac{20-x}{8})$ since $\frac{20-x}{8}$ is the ratio of the sides of the triangle in the form $\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$.

Now, using some algebraic manipulation to move information around,

$\tan(\theta) = \frac{20-x}{8}$

$x = 20-8\tan(\theta)$

For the purposes of answering the second two parts of the question, the original form I gave, $\theta = \arctan(\frac{20-x}{8})$ is easier to use.

If the race is just starting, $x=0$, so plug $0$ into the equation to get $\theta$.  And then, if the son has swum 25 meters, $x=25$ and so plug that into the equation and see the result from there.